# Use parsley.js for certain areas of a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I'm using parsley.js (parsleyjs.org) in combination with acc-wizard.js (http://sathomas.me/acc-wizard/).

Is there a way to make parsley check only a certain region (see following code, e.g. `region one`, which could contain 5 input fields) instead of the whole form?

```
<form>
    <div id="one">fields for parsley.js to validate...</div>
    <div id="two">fields for parsley.js to validate...</div>
    <div id="three">fields for parsley.js to validate...</div>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initiate Parsley via JavaScript so that you can pass in custom options. Then you can just use the **excluded** param to remove whichever sections of the form you don't wish to validate.

http://jsfiddle.net/5JA8R/

```
$('form').parsley({
    excluded: '.two input, .three input'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the idea. I'll just write a function which does field-checks for the individual parts and return .parsley('validate') for the blocks! Cheers

Comment: Excellent! Glad you figured out a solution.

Answer (score 6):

Good news, Parsley2 now have a `group` option that allows to define different areas on a form and validate them separately :)

Tadaa: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/multisteps.html