# How to validate only selected fields using parsley js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I'm using parsley js in two forms in a single page. i want to trigger parsley validator when i click on a type='button' field and validate the first form to check only 3 fields of the form. Initially there are around 7 fields in the form included for validation. So far I couldn't make it work. tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476515/use-parsley-js-for-certain-areas-of-a-form)  but no luck.

any idea?

update: this is my code;

```
<div class = 'two'>
    <input type='text' id='firstname' name='firstname' />
</div>
$('#form').parsley({
    excluded: '.two input'
});
$('#form').parsley('validate');
```

i just tried to exclude one field and test if the form is validating as i want it to be. But still it validates input field inside css class 'two'. that's all i have done so far. no clue..

Comment: Can you post the html and javascript that you have so far, or better yet, create a jsfiddle so we can test it? Have you tried `data-parsley-group` to validate a portion of your form?

Answer (score 12):

You have a couple of issues with your code, specifically with this line:

```
<dir classs = 'two'>
```

that should be

```
<div class = 'two'>
```

That is, you have `dir` instead of `div` and `classs` instead of `class`. You should also use `$('#form').parsley().validate()` instead of `$('#form').parsley('validate')`.

The following code will work:

```
<form method='post' id='form'>
    <div class = 'two'>
        <input type='text' id='firstname' name='firstname' required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type='text' id='thisisrequired' name='thisisrequired' required />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="submit-form">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form').parsley({
            excluded: '.two input'
        });

        $("#submit-form").on('click', function() {
            $('#form').parsley().validate();
            if ($('#form').parsley().isValid()) {
                console.log('valid');
            } else {
                console.log('not valid');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can view a more complete working example in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/bv7bh7tz/)

---

For your case, you should consider using `data-parsley-group` ([see the docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-field)) to achieve the same result, with the following code:

```
<form method='post' id='form'>
    <div>
        <input type='text' id='firstname' name='firstname' data-parsley-group="first" 
            required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type='text' id='thisisrequired' name='thisisrequired' 
            data-parsley-group="second" required />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="submit-form">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form').parsley();

        $("#submit-form").on('click', function() {
            $('#form').parsley().validate("second");
            if ($('#form').parsley().isValid()) {
                console.log('valid');
            } else {
                console.log('not valid');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The difference between the two, is that in the first example you redefine the `excluded`option. In the second example you would use `data-parsley-group` and validate only that group.

For a complete example, visit [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ukgvam9k/) (you can test it and change  `$('#form').parsley().validate("second");` to `$('#form').parsley().validate("first");` to see what happens).

Answer (score 1):

just an add on to the answer above, to work correctly ,
use group name in isValid too,ie $('#form').parsley().isValid(**"second"**)).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form').parsley();

        $("#submit-form").on('click', function() {
            $('#form').parsley().validate("second");
            if ($('#form').parsley().isValid(**"second"**)) {
                console.log('valid');
            } else {
                console.log('not valid');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```