# JS Parsley validate only some fields in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

Here I have an form and I validate that form with parsley js:

```
<form id="form" parsley-validate>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"
        parsley-minlength="5"
        parsley-required="true"
    />

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname"
        parsley-minlength="5"
        parsley-required="true"
    />

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email"
        parsley-required="true"
        parsley-type="email"
    />
<!--
    <label for="email">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw"
        parsley-minlength="8"
        parsley-required="true"
    />
    <input type="password" name="pw-verify"
        parsley-equalto="#pw"
        parsley-required="true"
    />
-->

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
    <button id="validate" >VALIDATE ONLY NAME and Last Name</button>
```

but now I need when I click on button id=validate to validate only name and lname fields in form, so I dont want to submit form just want to validate that fileds?

Is that possible?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/RT5aN/405/

Answer (score 2):

You can use validation groups ([data-parsley-group](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-field)).  See this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930039/how-to-validate-only-selected-fields-using-parsley-js).

You can also fire validation whenever you want.  It doesn't have to be only at submission.  Just wire up a button to a function and call:

```
$('#myForm').parsley().validate("my-validation-group");
```

or omit the group name and it'll validate everything.